# Can I call HOC directly from within JSX / TSX in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

I have a React HOC in TypeScript, but it doesn't seem to work when I call it from within a TSX Component `render` method.  Here's an example:

```js
export class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return <div>Hello, world!</div>;
    }
}

export const withRedText = (Component) => {
    return class WithRedComponent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
        public render(): JSX.Element {                
            return (
                <div style={{color: "red"}}>
                    <Component {...this.props} />
                </div>
            );
        }
    };
}; 

export const HelloWorldComponentWithRedText = withRedText(HelloWorldComponent);
```

I'm calling this from a parent JSX file like this:

```js
public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
       <div>
           Test #1: <HelloWorldComponent/>
           Test #2: <HelloWorldComponentWithRedText />
           Test #3: { withRedText(<HelloWorldComponent />) }
       </div>
    )
}
```

The first and second tests work as expected---the text is red in the second one.  But the third line renders nothing.  I expected the second and third lines to be the same.

When I step through it with the debugger, the argument to Test #2 is a Component of type `HelloWorldComponent`, but Test #3 is seeing a `Component = Object {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), ...}`.

Is there a way to dynamically wrap a Component with syntax like `{ withRedText(<HelloWorldComponent />) }` from within the JSX/TSX file?

(TypeScript 2.1.4 & React 15.4.0)

[Here it is on CodePen](http://codepen.io/mikebridge/pen/zNjexW)

Comment: Here's a JavaScript version: http://codepen.io/mikebridge/pen/mRLvRd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can invoke a HOC directly / implicitly from JSX.  Thinking about the implementation of JSX and how HOCs work, I don't think it would be good for performance: every time the component re-renders, it calls the HOC function again, re-creates the wrapped component class, then invokes it.

You can often get a similar effect, though, by creating a component that takes another component as a parameter:

```
const WithRedText = ({component: Component, children, ...props}) => (
    <div style={{color: "red"}}>
      <Component {...props}>{children}</Component>
    </div>
);
```

(I'm passing `component` as lowercase, because that seems to be the convention for props, but within `WithRedText`, I uppercase it, because that's how JSX identifies custom components as opposed to HTML tags.)

Then, to use it:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <div className="container">
        <WithRedText component={HelloWorldComponent} />
    </div>,
);
```

See http://codepen.io/joshkel/pen/MJGLOQ.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thanks.  I was ultimately wondering if I could stack them up dynamically, e.g. `{withFeatureOne(withFeatureTwo(<HelloWorldComponent />))}` but maybe that will only work statically.

Comment: After thinking about your answer I realized I was asking the wrong question.  I can't call the HOC like I was thinking, but I can still get decent syntax using `React.CreateComponent()`.  I could clean it up with a helper function like `export const createComponent = (component, ...args) => React.createElement(component, args);` then calling that from JSX like this: `{createComponent(withRedText(HelloWorldComponent))`.  I can chain those as much as I want and the syntax isn't too hard on the eyes.

Answer (score 1):

That is because in test #3 you pass it an instance: `<HelloWorldComponent />`, instead of the type/class `HelloWorldComponent`. The JSX gets transpiled to what amounts to a lot of object instantiation boilerplate.